# Dask LocalCluster creating threads inside subprocesses

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I'm new to dask and I seem to have some issues with something that should be fairly straight forward so I'm sure I'm missing something.

I have a program that supposed to poll messages from kafka, then sends chucks of messages per partition to subprocess and then creates a new thread per message and then each thread should preserve its data to redis (thats why I chose each message as thread since there are a lot of calls to a DB).

This is the code that I tried to use (its the core of my dask usage):

```
class ConsumerMultiprocessing:
    def __init__(self, num_of_workers: int = None, threads_per_worker: int = None, future_timeout: int = 0,
                 memory_limit: str = '2GB', **kwargs: Any):
        self._configurator = Configurator()
        self._logger = LoggerManager().get_logger()
        self._subprocess_function = MessageSubprocess().run
        self._local_cluster = LocalCluster(n_workers=num_of_workers, threads_per_worker=threads_per_worker,
                                           memory_limit=memory_limit, timeout=future_timeout, **kwargs)
        self._client = Client(address=self._local_cluster.scheduler_address)
        self._logger.info(f'dashboard link to for dask monitoring link={self._client.dashboard_link}')

    def _fire_and_forget(self, function: Callable, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        future = self._client.submit(function, **kwargs)
        fire_and_forget(future)

    def run(self) -> None:
        while True:
            topic_partitions = self._consumer.poll(timeout_ms=self._poll_timeout_ms)
            self._set_messages_encryption_key(topic_partitions)
            for topic_partition, messages in topic_partitions.items():
                polled_messages += len(messages)
                self._logger.info(f"processing topic_partition={topic_partition.partition} messages_count={len(messages)}")
                self._fire_and_forget(self._subprocess_function, partition_number=topic_partition.partition,
                                      messages=messages, decryption_keys=self._decryption_keys_mapper, cluster_address=self._local_cluster.scheduler_address)


class MessageSubprocess:
    def run(self, messages: list[ConsumerRecord], partition_number: int, decryption_keys: dict, cluster_address: str) -> None:
        with Client(address=cluster_address) as client:
            for message in messages:
                client.submit(<some_function>, message=message, decryption_keys=decryption_keys)
```

Now I can't figure out where should I specify the in `ConsumerMultiprocessing` it should use processes and in `MessageSubprocess` it should use threads, because when I add to each client the argument `processes=True/False` I get an error message that client does not recognize this argument and if I give the local cluster this argument its affecting both of them would use whats I decided there and I cant differentiate. What am I missing?!

Also is this a good way to use dask? I need this to support high scale of 2000 messages/ sec, and I'm afraid its going to open a lot of threads and processes at the same time and make the pod explode

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your code, you have an "outer" loop with a Client defined, and each task it fires then also created a Client and submits further work. Since you define your LocalCluster only once, this should not result in an explosion of processes or threads, but probably a *lot* of tasks. It seems like you are passing around small batches of kafka messages polled in the main thread, but what you actually want to do is have different workers fetch those messages. But why not just measure if this method is working for you and meets the required scale?

By the way, the not-very-recent [streamz](https://github.com/python-streamz/streamz) package has kafka and dask integration, designed for high-throughput realtime processing (e.g., GPU specific blog post: https://medium.com/rapids-ai/the-custreamz-series-the-accelerated-kafka-datasource-4faf0baeb3f6 ).

Comment: The method I posted have one major issue and its memory leak...
I think its from the `while True` without reseting the `Client` but I'm not sure. So every new message increases my memory and its not going down.
Do you maybe have a suggestion on how I could fix my code?

Also streamz looks interesting! I'll give it a go, thanks!!

Comment: "a suggestion on how I could fix my code" - I would start with doing away with the classes, they are not adding anything for you.